# QGIS SQL Query for Blank

Tags: qgis, sql

I'm trying to write a query that excludes all entries with the zone AG but would include any blank entries. I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Zone <> "AG" and Zone = "Null"
```

Any suggestions for how to build this?

Comment: use IS NULL not =Null

Comment: use `or`, not `and` between the two terms

Answer (score 1):

Answer already given by Mapperz and JGH...

```
Zone <> 'AG' OR Zone IS NULL
```

Not sure how `Zone IS NULL` part is needed, but there may be hidden context.